# I am trying to run my first word count application in spark through jupyter. But I am getting error in the initialization of SparkContext

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run my first word count application in spark through jupyter. But I am getting error in the initialization of SparkContext.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Count")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

**Below is the error:**

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-6b825dbb354c> in <module>()
----> 1 sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

/home/master/Desktop/Apps/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py in __init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls)
    113         """
    114         self._callsite = first_spark_call() or CallSite(None, None, None)
--> 115         SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
    116         try:
    117             self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,

/home/master/Desktop/Apps/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py in _ensure_initialized(cls, instance, gateway, conf)
    270                         " created by %s at %s:%s "
    271                         % (currentAppName, currentMaster,
--> 272                             callsite.function, callsite.file, callsite.linenum))
    273                 else:
    274                     SparkContext._active_spark_context = instance

ValueError: Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once; existing SparkContext(app=PySparkShell, master=local[*]) created by <module> at /usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.py:186
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you already have a SparkContext object that is created by Jupyter automatically. You shouldn't have to create a new one.

Just type sc in a cell and execute it. It should display a reference to an existing context

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

In fact the error indicated it already:

> ValueError: Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once